# Laravel change request input from string to array

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm building an API with custom query filter, in my filter, there are rules that value cannot be empty and some fields has to be an array.

I have managed to filter out empty fields if they are submitted but I can't convert request input to the array,  is there a way to do it?

Here is my code:

```
public function removeEmptyFieldsFromRequest($request)
{

    $emptyFields = [];

    foreach ($request->all() as $name => $value)
    {
        if (is_null($value)){
            $emptyFields[] = $name;
        }


        $fields = ['transmissions', 'grades', 'colors', 'equipment', 'lots', 'chassis', 'auctions', 'models'];

        if (in_array($name, $fields)){

           // here need to convert request value from a string into the array
        }


    }

    $request = $request->except($emptyFields);

    return $request;
}
```

I want to make this filter usable in different cases, I know that I can change the input name to the array on the front end

Comment: does your query string looks like this `?array_field[]=val1&array_field[]=val2` ?

Comment: @CodeZilla no, unfortunately, that is the problem. This is API I can't control the front end,  but I can add validation but will be cool if system convert it automatically

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel if your parameters is like field[0],field[1],...
you can get it with `$request->field` and it is array so you can check

```
is_array($request->field)
```

and in your case you can check it with below code

```
is_array($value)
```

Comment: I try ` is_array($request->input($name));` but it didn't helped

Answer (score 1):

if you query string is like this : `/?a=1&b=2&a=3&c=1&a=2`.

You can create a function that parses the query string something like this:

```
$uri = explode('?', Request::capture()->getRequestUri());
$queryStringArr = explode('&',$uri[1]);
$params = [];
foreach ($queryStringArr as $item) {
    $i = explode('=',$item);
    if (!empty($params[$i[0]])){
        $params[$i[0]]=array_merge((is_array($params[$i[0]]))?$params[$i[0]]:[$params[$i[0]]],[$i[1]]);
    }else{
        $params[$i[0]]=$i[1];
    }
}
print_r($params);die;
```

Which gives.

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 2
        )

    [b] => 2
    [c] => 1
)
```

I haven't tested it much so give it a thought yourself.